# how can i maintain a modern static website without transpiler or bundler tools

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, requirejs

We have a static website, we outsource the website maintenance, we don't have source code repository, so contractor edits the code on production server directly.

It has no problem, as our website built decades ago with old school html4 only. What it store on the web server, is what the source code is.

At today, the web site can be composed by UI framework, eg. Vue, React....etc. Sometimes the HTML file contains web components and other JS module. I have done a little google to learn that, building a website today need NPM, NodeJs, Webpack, Gulp....etc, they manage js module and bundle / built the production code...

My problem is, we like to revamp our website with modern UI (HTML5, CSS3, mobile friendly...). The tools I just mentioned will "process" the source code and output production code. We don't have the source code server (eg. git server), for our contractor to store the source code. ( our company management doesn't allow us to purchase private repository services on the internet. eg..github, gitlab...etc).

Can I keep using the old school way? the source code on the production web server is always the only source code...

I have tried myself to using the require.js, it loads js module on the browser, so I can handle module loading without node.js and Webpack, and writing the web component in vanilla js. Is it the only solution I can do?

Comment: not having any vcs is - in my opinion - the bigger problem than deciding on transpiler/builder workflow. Any modernization will likely involve more then 1 person - how will you merge/coordinate ?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *could* continue to manage this site the "old school" way, but in doing so, you'll be ignoring the benefits that all the modern tools give you.

For example

- no git (or other version control) means no rolling back changes (or errors)
- using version control software also means you have a backup and you don't need to set up a backup scheme on the production server to save your files
- editing on the production server means if someone makes a typo, the site is messed up; etc.

I would **strongly** recommend modern tools; if cost is a concern, consider free tools:

- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) has long offered free private repositories; [Github](https://github.com/) has recently also started offering them.
- Tools such as [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), and others permit creation of static sites quickly and easily.

**Edit** in answer to some of the comments...

Switching to a more modern development workflow (including version control) is not just about saving money, it's also about:

- Does the employer/client want their developer(s) spending a lot of time managing the site - possibly including fixing problems - or do they want them working on something else?
- Is the employer/client willing to have periods of time when the site does not work correctly? As @birdspider mentions in the comments above, if you have multiple people working on the website on the production server, they're going to be messing up each others' work. Note that the use of a VCS helps avoid avoid some of the problems with people stepping on each others' toes and it also make **fixing** those conflicts *so much easier*.

If you approach the employer/client with these points and their answer is "we just don't like it", then there's probably not much else you can do. If I were in your shoes, I'd be strongly tempted to either a) implement something on my own (just to preserve my own sanity, although really this is probably not a good idea) or b) find a new job.

Comment: Thanks, Gitlab also free private too. I am sorry I doesn't say the reason why management don't allow buy git service, all I can say is not related to money. They just don't like it. They will ask a question, why we need it and we didn't need it. They will not accept technical reasons..... this is what my workplace is...

Comment: And about the Hugo, it generates site. After the site codes generated. How we maintain the site? Modify the Hugo "source", or the first time generated codes ?

Comment: Re: Hugo. Update the source, run Hugo to generate HTML/CSS/etc. files. Upload to production server